# GLSL blending modes, creating additive transparency

Tags: glsl, webgl, three.js

I have a little shader that looks like this, and has a neat effect.

```
uniform float beatScale;
varying vec3 vPos;

void main() {

  vec3 normPos = (normalize(vPos) + vec3(1, 1, 1)) / vec3(2, 2, 2);
  float alpha;

  if (normPos.y < beatScale - 0.1) {
    alpha = 0.0;
  } else if (normPos.y < beatScale) {
    alpha = 1.0 - (beatScale - normPos.y) / 0.1;
  } else {
    alpha = 1.0;
  }

  gl_FragColor = vec4(normPos, alpha);    
}
```

But the transparent parts of my objects in front block the objects behind, knocking out pixels that should have been rendered.

My sorry attempt was:

```
gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor + vec4(normPos, alpha);
```

But that didn't seem to change it.  I was hoping `gl_FragColor` had the previous pixel color, but no dice.

How can I add the computed color the color that was there before?  I don't care about what's on top, this is all glowy stuff I can simply add together.

Comment: In three.js, did you specify transparent=true on the material? The renderer runs through all opaque objects first with depth test painting, and then runs through transparent ones using alpha blending. I think the "transparent" flag is crucial here. Edit: oh, old question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing additive blending, then you should turn off depth writes.

Comment: Any idea how to make three.js do that?

Comment: You can get the contex from myWebGLRenderer.getContext() and do theContext.disable( theContext.DEPTH_TEST )

Comment: (r71) You can just set `material.depthTest` to `false`. The renderer will honour the setting.

Comment: It may be better to leave depthTest=true and set depthWrite=false, if you also have opaque objects in the scene.